Do I need to indicate 'solo' for wind/brass instruments in shared staff?
In an orchestral score, do I need to indicate 'solo' for wind/brass instruments passages in a shared staff?
In the below example, I have a passage that I want to be played by one horn (solo), but the staff is shared for two. If I'm not indicating 'A due' here, is it enough to understand it's solo or do I need to explicitly say it?


You need to say something at least to help the reader figure out which of the two horns should play the part.

If only Horn 1 is playing, you should place a “1” above the staff where that part begins.
Similarly, if/when Horn 2 gets to play on its own, place a “2” above the staff.
When both Horn 1 and Horn 2 are playing at the same time:

if they they are both playing the same part, write “a 2” (a due) above.
(If there was another horn sharing this staff then you’d need to be to be more specific with “1,2 a 2”.)
if they are playing different parts, it’s probably clear that Horn 1 is the upper voice and Horn 2 is the lower voice, so you won’t need to mark the numbers. But if it’s not obvious for some reason, when the parts have:

shared stems, write “1,2” above the staff.
stems in opposite directions, write a “1” above the staff and a “2” below.



If the instruction is for the part to be actually played in a soloistic way, instead write “1 solo” or “1,2 soli” etc.

Thanks for the answer! Do you have any score examples that I can check in IMSLP, for example, to understand the dynamics of your suggestions?

I feel like the last point about what “solo” means could be expanded. +1 anyway

@JoãoPaulo Prokofiev’s Romeo & Juliet ballet, Op. 64 has a few good examples of this notation in the first few pages of the Introduction of Act I. The horn section consists of 6 horns (Corni), but it uses uppercase Roman numerals to number them.  The same notation can be seen in the other woodwind and brass parts.

Thank you a lot!

I've never seen "1,2 a 2", but "a2" alone (with or without space) is quite common. It's also common to use roman numerals to indicate which part has to play, in place of arabic ones, often followed by a period. The solo indication may also not require the number, as it's assumed that "solo" is for one (first or third, unless specified) and "soli" for both.

If you have stems going in opposite directions it's probably unnecessary to write a "1." above the staff and a "2." below.  Even with shared stems, it should be clear that a wind instrument can't play two notes at once (unless you're calling for multiphonics, which as a non-standard technique probably need their own special notation.)

@musicamante There’s an example of “I.II a2” on p. 20 (and a couple on p. 24) of the score I mentioned in my previous comment, but this is only because the other horn staves are not shown.  You’re right that this is usually redundant.

@MichaelSeifert Yeah, it’s probably unnecessary in most cases, but occasionally Horn 1 can be scored lower than Horn 2.

One option if both horn players are performing from the same stave would be to notate the horn 1 part stems up, horn 2 part stems down.
But a direction saying "one player only" is a good idea too - removes any lingering uncertainty.
